# How to style the UI element in Xamarin.mac without changing the underlying functionality

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am using switch element in Xamarin.macOS. It appear as a checkbox in macOS, but I want it to look like Cupertino switch (iOs switch). I am aware that I can create a custom switch in Xamarin.macOS. But doing so I am creating an entirely new element with the events and functionality. My problem statement is to use the existing switch element and switch renderer provided by xamarin.macOS and just to change the UI style of the switch element to look like iOS switch. please let me know if there is any way to accomplish this without having to create a custom control.

I am using dependency service to add platform specific code to perform styling of UI elements.